# Through the Google Places API, how can I search for *all* nearby places, ranked by distance?

Tags: web-services, google-places-api

I'm using the endpoint `https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search` described here: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

There is a documented query parameter `rankby` which can be set to distance. The documentation states that if I specify `rankby=distance` I have to further narrow down the search by either `keyword`, `name` or `type`. I don't want to narrow down my search, yet I still want to search ranked by distance. Is there a way to achieve that?